# how to launch a (.exe) file in C++ using a window form application?

Tags: .net, visual-c++, c++-cli, base-class-library

, when the user clicks on Pre sets button  for example it would launch another (.exe) file , same goes for Bread board button .

This is the code i have been using

```
namespace RC_lab {
    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentMode1;         
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;
    using namespace System::Diagnostics;
```

as for the button it is like

```
Process::Start("PreSets.exe");
```

but it gives me an error , this code works for

```
Process::Start("notepad.exe");
Process::Start("chrome.exe");
```

it would launch them corretly , but in my case i get:

> Win32Exception was unhandeld  The system cannot find the file specfied .

i made sure the file exist even place the folder in the program files in the C partation .

Comment: You should make sure the file exists. EDIT: A more useful comment would be is to either make sure the windows PATH variable is setup properly, or use a fully qualified path.

Comment: I added the .exe file in the refrences in the solution explorer but it would give the same error

Answer (score 3):

```
Process::Start("C:\\application_directory\\PreSets.exe");
```

You have to specify the location of the file as well.

Comment: you did change the C:\application_directory with actual path to the file right. Check if the file exists first

Comment: I mean check programmatically if the file exists. Also give me the exact path of the file and your application

Comment: The correct path would be "C:\\application_directory\\PreSets.exe"

Comment: yes i did change it to the actual path but still the same error

Comment: try dreta's variation C:\\application_directory\\PreSets.exe

Answer (score 1):

just add

1. `using namespace System::Diagnostics;` in given default namespace .
2. and add `Process::Start("chrome.exe");` into button.

Answer (score 0):

You can also launch  the exe file or any other file by using OpenFileDialog .
See the code below

```
     // Displays an OpenFileDialog so the user can select a Cursor.
  Stream^ myStream;
      OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;


      openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
      openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

      if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
      {
         if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
         {

            String^ strfilename = openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1->FileName;


              Process::Start(strfilename);


            myStream->Close();
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to change all "\" to "/". I caught that when I saw the warnings of my project.
For example c:Desktop\ex.exe to C:/Desktop/ex.exe.